# Subscribing to Trello Boards or Cards not giving notifications

Tags: notifications, trello-cards, trello-boards

I am not getting email notifications from Boards or from Cards I subscribe to.

I have subscribed to cards on boards I have also subscribed to (so doubly subscribed). 
I only see the notifications if I go to Trello in my browser.

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Are you sure you made your email settings set to "Instantly?" If you have the "Periodically" option set, you will only receive an email every hour or so.

2 - On top of that, if you check Trello often (often enough to view the notifications directly before an email is sent), then you might not get email updates.

> You are emailed a collection of unread notifications. Email summaries
>   won't include any notifications you've already read on the site.

Comment: Email settings are set to Instantly. I was not checking Trello often because I expected to get the notifications. I now check once or twice a day.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the email is going into a Spam folder? If you are using Gmail, you might have a filter set up that is mistakenly making it skip the inbox?

Comment: FWIW, we use Trello at work and I do get emails 100% ok into my GMail account. I would definately check the SPAM folder (or even make a RULE) and of course, the email settings in your Trello Account.